# How to call the appropriate parameter on

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This might be very basic question to some but I am struggling for quite some time.

I created an aspx page which has a search ability on User Table (Database). When Search button is cliked related Grid is filled with UserNames. And I put an Edit HyperLink in every row right next to UserName Column.

However Edit button should get a parameter named "UserCode" (this information also comes when I retrieved the names) but I just couldn't write the appropriate code to the related line. Please in my codes there is a line contains **I DONT KNOW WHAT TO TYPE IN HERE**. Instead of index solution, any other suggestions are welcome.

```
    DataTable oDataTable;
    DataView oDataView;

    protected void SearchLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MembershipUserCollection allUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers();
        if (allUsers != null)
        {
            oDataTable = new SystemUserAccountBsWrapper().SearchAllUsers(null); //Fetchs all user data
            oDataView = oDataTable.DefaultView;
            oDataView.Sort = "UserName";
            oDataView.RowFilter = "UserName LIKE '%" + UserNameTextBox.Text + "%'";
            UserGridView.DataSource = oDataView;
            UserGridView.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void UserGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink EditHyperLink = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("EditHyperLink");
            EditHyperLink.NavigateUrl("EditUserInfo.aspx?key=" + oDataTable.Rows[**I DONT KNOW WHAT TO TYPE IN HERE**]["UserCode"]);
        }
    }
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DataBinder.Eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx) can be used on codebehind also

```
EditHyperLink
      .NavigateUrl("EditUserInfo.aspx?key=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,"UserCode"),650, 500, true);
```

Comment: you are no different than a war hero in my eyes. Thank you. and Thank you everyone who tried their best to help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need the DataIndex:

```
protected void UserGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink EditHyperLink = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("EditHyperLink");
        EditHyperLink.NavigateUrl=("EditUserInfo.aspx?key=" + oDataTable.Rows[e.Row.DataItemIndex]["UserCode"], 650, 500, true);
    }
}
```

But there's a better way to do that:

```
<columns>
    <asp:HyperLinkColumn
                 HeaderText="Edit"
                 DataNavigateUrlField="UserCode"
                 DataNavigateUrlFormatString="EditUserInfo.aspx?key={0}"
                 Text="Edit"
                 Target="_blank"
                 />
 </columns>
```

Comment: too bad DataItem index brings everytime same index for different searches.

Answer (score 0):

`e.Row` gives you the current row, you shouldn't have to access the oDataTable.Rows by index.

So, that would be:

```
e.Row["UserCode"]
```

instead of:

```
oDataTable.Rows[**I DONT KNOW WHAT TO TYPE IN HERE**]["UserCode"]
```

Comment: but I tried e.Row.TabIndex, e.Row.RowIndex, e.Row.DataItemIndex. Non of them worked :(

Comment: VS is underlined e.Row["UserCode"] and saying **Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type GridViewRow**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the e.Row.DataItem to obtain the values you require, for example...

```
// If you require the first item in the row use...
e.Row.DataItem[0]
```

If I'm using a strongly typed Datarow / object, I prefer to cast that into its strongly typed form, i.e.

```
// For datarows
(MyTypedDataRow)((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem.Row).MyPropertyName;
```

HTH